# Incomplete gamma function for integral with positive exponential

Tags: gamma-function, gaussian-integral, analytic-continuation

In my research I encountered the following indefinite integral
$$
I=\int x^{n-1/2}e^{x}dx,
$$

which looks pretty much like an incomplete Gamma function with the little caveat that in the exponential term I have a positive sign instead of a minus sign. My naive solution was to do the change of variables x=-u:

$$
I=(-1)^{n-1/2}\int u^{n-1/2}e^{-u}du=(-1)^{n-1/2} \Gamma(n+1/2,u),
$$

But when plugging my integral in wolfram I get a different result. This is what I get:
$$
I=(-x)^{1/2 - n} x^{-1/2 + n} Γ(n+1/2, -x)
$$

which differs slightly from what I have. My advisor told me that I should instead consider the analytical continuation of the integral but I really know how to do so, could someone please give me some insight. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your integral lower and upper limits?

Comment: I think your error is the assumption $(-u)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}=(-1)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\ u^{n-\frac{1}{2}}$ which is not generally true.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption

$$(-u)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}=(-1)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\ u^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{1}$$

is only valid for $u\ge 0$ and

$$\int x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\ e^x\,dx=(-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\ x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2},-x\right)=-i\ (-1)^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2},-x\right),\quad x\le 0\tag{2}$$

is equivalent to

$$-(-1)^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \int u^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\ e^{-u}\,du=-i\ (-1)^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2},u\right),\quad u\ge 0\tag{3}$$

since $x=-u$ and $dx=-du$.